# Proof $2$ Lines Are Parallel

Tags: geometry

[image]Hi. I tutor a group of kids in grade $10$ and one of them brought up a question taken from a geometry problem book whose diagram is shown above. I have tried for an hour but get nowhere. I could do it with contradiction proof but got tired with other things...So I posted here and if you have a proof, I want to see it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are $c$ and $d$ parallel?

Comment: https://gradestack.com/CBSE-Class-9th-Complete/Lines-and-Angles/Theorem-5-Converse-of/14900-2953-3975-study-wtw

Comment: The anonymous angle beside $1$ is a corresponding angle of both $3,8$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lines $a$ and $b$ aren't necessarily parallel (unless $c$ and $d$ are supposed to be parallel). Just redraw the picture, keeping the angles fixed, but making it so $c$ and $d$ don't look parallel (or imagine grabbing the point with the angles $5$,$6$,$7$,$8$ and rotating that point and the lines $a$ and $d$ just a little bit).

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure where they are in the class; but, could you use the angles. We know that a set of parallel lines intersected by a transversal gives us that the alternate interior are congruent and that the alternate exterior angles are congruent. So we know that a and b are parallel if the alternate interior angle for angle 8 is 105 degrees this same angle is the alternate exterior angle for 3 which also has a measure of 105 degrees. You may be able to use the fact that 3 and 8 are both 105 degrees to prove that the other angle is 105 degrees and then the lines are congruent.